# Problems with Terminal output garbled when using ConTeXt

Tags: errors, context-mkii

when using texexec to compile my documents my terminal is sometimes garbled, so I can't read any error messages anymore :(
But since this only happened a very few times, I couldn't be really bothered until now.

But lately I've started to use tmux on one working computer i just ssh into, but now whenever I run texec terminal output is garbled. I can reset the terminal, but still if an error is happening I have no chance to see the error message :(

I copied a small part of my output, so you can hopefully see what I'm talking about:

```
systems         : end file ENotes at line 3
system          : command \x is already defined
(./notes.tuo) (./notes.tuo) (./notes.tuo) (./notes.tuo) (./notes.tuo)
(./notes.tuo) (./notes.tuo) (./notes.tuo) (./notes.tuo) (./notes.tuo)
(./notes.tuo)
publications    : loading database from notes.bbl
(./notes.bbl) (./notes.tuo)
systems         : begin file notes at line 23
(./msf_intro.tex
subject         : - Master Stability Function
) (./msf_delgap.tex
subject         : - Master Stability Function + Gap Junction + Delays

Overfull \hbox (4.03052pt too wide) detected at line 41
\*12ptmmmirm*: J\*12ptmmsyrm*: f[] \*12ptmmmirm*: G[]H\*12ptmmmrrm*: ([][]\*12p
tmmmirm*: ; [][][][]\*12ptmmmrrm*: )\*12ptmmsyrm*: g \*12ptmmmrrm*: = \*12ptmmm
irm*: J[]\*12ptmmsyrm*: f[] \*12ptmmmirm*: G[]H\*12ptmmmrrm*: ([][]\*12ptmmmirm
*: ; [][][][]\*12ptmmmrrm*: )\*12ptmmsyrm*: g\*12ptmmmirm*: [] \*12⎻├└└└⎼⎼└*: 
→ \*12⎻├└└└☃⎼└*: J[]\*12⎻├└└⎽≤⎼└*: °[] \*12⎻├└└└☃⎼└*: G[]H\*12⎻├└└└⎼⎼└*: ([][]\
*12⎻├└└└☃⎼└*: ; [][][][]\*12⎻├└└└⎼⎼└*: )\*12⎻├└└⎽≤⎼└*: ±
°⎺┼├⎽           : ⎼e⎽e├├☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e ┌☃⎽├
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: ⎺⎼☃±☃┼▒┌↑b▒⎽e
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: ┌└↑└▒├▒
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: ┌└↑⎼└
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: ├e│┼▒┼⎽☃↑b▒⎽e
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: ec↑b▒⎽e
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: ─│↑b▒⎽e
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: ├5↑b▒⎽e
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: 8⎼↑b▒⎽e
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: ⎺⎼☃±☃┼▒┌↑▒└⎽↑b▒⎽e
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: ⎺⎼☃±☃┼▒┌↑▒└⎽↑e┤┌e⎼
°⎺┼├⎽           : ┤⎽☃┼± └▒⎻ °☃┌e: ⎺⎼☃±☃┼▒┌↑⎻┤b┌☃c↑┌└
(/A⎻⎻┌☃c▒├☃⎺┼⎽/C⎺┼TeX├/├e│/├e│└°↑c⎺┼├e│├/├e│/c⎺┼├e│├/b▒⎽e/⎽⎺⎼├↑de°↓└┐☃☃)
```

and so on...

thanks!

Comment: Snowmen, they are everywhere!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the overfull hbox reporting, so fixing the formula first so that it no longer generates an overfull hbox would fix the immediate problem.

What happens is that the engine (pdftex, probably) is outputting a character that confuses the terminal emulator.

I realise that while this may be an answer, it is not a solution. But for that, I will need more information like the actual formula input, and your context version (both the macro/context version identifier and the pdftex version).

Comment: thanks, but since had to continue working on my document the problem seems to be gone for now and unfortunately despite having had this problem for a while I couldn't reproduce it yet.